# Draw / lay out contents of a wide UIView inside UIScrollView, outside of a ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uikit

I'm trying to make a large `UIScrollView` with various UI elements on it which is larger (wider) than the iPhone's screen.

I'd like to be able to lay those elements out in a `UIView`, and then load that `UIView` into the `UIScrollView`. This way, I can clearly see in Interface Builder what I'm doing with that large view.

How can I do this, with Storyboards active? I'm trying to do something similar to the #2 example here, but using Storyboards:

http://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/05/18/uiscrollview-examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this tutorial from Ray Wenderlich helps, which goes into pretty good detail about `UIScrollView` :

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10518/how-to-use-uiscrollview-to-scroll-and-zoom-content

If you're doing layout programmatically, please take note of this important comment:

`You might ask why we don’t do all of the above in viewDidLoad, and you’d be right to ask. The reason you can’t is that the view size isn’t definitely known until viewWillAppear:, and since you use the size of scrollView when calculating the minimum zoom, things might go wrong if we do it in viewDidLoad.`

Good luck!